# Inequalities related to infimum and supremum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f,g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions on a closed rectangle $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $P$ be a partition of $A$ and $S \in P$ a sub-rectangle. Show that:

$m_S(f+g) \geq m_S(f)+m_S(g)$ and $M_S(f+g) \leq M_S(f)+ M_S(g)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok at first we will prove that 
$$\inf_{S}(f+g)\geq \inf_S f +\inf_S g$$

For this we use that 
$$g\geq \inf_S g$$
because of the definition of infimum.
Hence 
$$\inf_S ( f+ g) \geq \inf_S( f+\inf_S g)$$
On the other hand $\inf_S g$ is only a constant, hence
$$\inf_S (f+\inf_S g)=\inf_S f + \inf_S g$$

Now we prove that 
$$\sup (f+g)\leq \sup f+\sup g.$$
The proof is nearly the same we use that 
$$g\leq \sup g$$ 
because of the definition of supremum.
Hence 
$$\sup(f+g)\leq \sup(f+\sup g)$$
As $\sup g$ is only a constant we get again 
$$\sup(f+\sup g) =\sup f +\sup g $$
Hence 
$$\sup (f+g) \leq \sup f + \sup g$$